# Error with Jest and React navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm having problems when doing **unit tests** with **jest**:

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
>
> ```
>   at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:42:15)
>   at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:35:7)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/src/Helpers/FunctionCallTagHandler/index.io
> ```
>
> s.js:16:37)
>         at Object. (node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/src/GoogleTagManager.js:2:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem earlier. Can suggest a workaround. This problem occurs with `react-native-google-analytics-bridge` only for iOS, so you can switch your jest default platform to Android.

In your `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "haste": {
      "defaultPlatform": "android",
      "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
      ],
      "providesModuleNodeModules": [
        "react",
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: "thanks" i have other error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInitialNotification' of undefined
NotificationsComponent.Object.<anonymous>.NotificationsComponent.getInitialNotification (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/component/index.android.js:20:31)
      at Object.<anonymous>.Notifications.callNative (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/index.js:39:10)
      at Object.<anonymous>.Notifications.popInitialNotification (node_modules/react-native-push-notification/index.js:302:7)

Comment: When I try this solution, I get this error instead:
`setup.js: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of 'jest.mock()' is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables. Invalid variable access: console` However, my setup.js file makes no reference to console. I'm confused.